# Nextjs redirect the Dynamic route to homepage after reload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Peace Upon you, my brother.

Here this is my next js project - [git Repo](https://github.com/NoorBhuiyan/redirect-problem)

After making this project i hit "npm run build" and "npm run export"

and then upload the - out folder on cpalen.

I found everything is working good without the Dynamic Route [id].js

when i refresh any ID then it redirect me to the homepage which is too much annoying. What to do if i want to visit the exact route? help me out brother !

Comment: Have you tried adding `trailingSlash: true` to the `next.config.js`?

Answer (score 0):

By using the `npm run export` command you are only generating static HTML and not the Node.js server. I noticed you use `getServerSideProps` on the blog[id].js page which is not supported when using `npm run export`. You will need to convert `getServerSideProps` to `getStaticPaths`

Comment: No man. I did not use getServerSideProps. Please check it again. It is just a plain dynamic route.

Comment: I have double checked your repo, please look at line 15. You export `getServerSideProps` and fetch posts from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/`
 https://github.com/NoorBhuiyan/dynamic_route_error/blob/main/pages/blog/%5Bid%5D.js#L15